# How can I access the open form in an Excel VSTO add-in using C# code in Workbook_Open of ThisAddInclass?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, office-addins

'Please know the code to run fmX of the open form in Workbook_Open of c# Excel ThisAddInclass'

```
public partial class fmX : Form {
    public fmX() {
        InitializeComponent();
        xl.Application app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;            
        foreach (xl.Workbook wb in app.Workbooks) this.listBox1.Items.Add(wb.Name);
    }
}


public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookOpen += Workbook_Open;
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {}

    private void Workbook_Open(xl.Workbook wb) {
        //this code ~~~
    }
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
}
```

'i want to know in //this code ~~~'

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an instance of the `fmX` class in the add-in class in the following way:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private fmX formInstance;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.WorkbookOpen += Workbook_Open;
    }
```

And then in the `Open` event you can create a new instance and display it to a user:

```
private void Workbook_Open(xl.Workbook wb) {
     formInstance = new fmX();
     formInstance.Show();
    }
```

Be aware, to avoid any issues with overlapping the dialog box with other windows or dialogs you need to specify the parent window handle when the `Show` method is called. Use the [IWin32Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) interface for specifying the parent window handle. This interface is implemented on objects that expose Win32 HWND handles (including Office applications).

Comment: Thank you, but Currently, fmx is open. I want to access the listbox in there. 
example,,, formInstance.listbox1~~~

Comment: Where do you create a form instance and display it to a user?

Comment: Anyway, you need to declare a form instance at the class level as stated in my post and then you can access it from any event handler in your add-in.